# How do I select the scrollbar of a div?

Tags: html, css

I know how to change the style of scrollbars for an entire page using CSS such as webkit-scrollbar codes.

However, how I only want to target the scroll bar in a div (not the browser's div). How can I accomplish this without using JavaScript or jQuery?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Have you tried a basic descendant selector?

Comment: What do you mean by "target"? And please provide relevant codes along with your question.

Comment: Could you add an excerpt of your code - or link us to something live; and perhaps better outline what it is you're trying to achieve?

From there I'm sure one of us could better assist you.

Comment: this? http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, just use `overflow:hidden;` or `overflow-y:hidden;` on the desired div

```css
div{box-sizing:border-box;}
#red{padding:5px;width:100%;height:1500px;background:red;}
#green{width:60%;height:900px;background:palegreen;overflow-y:hidden;}
```

```html
<div id="red">
  <div id="green">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
.class::scrollbar
```

Can also use the prefixes.

```
.class::-webkit-scrollbar
```